# HibernateTemplate get() is working but save() is neither throwing any error not inserting into DB

Tags: spring, hibernate

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rksambari"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mysessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>/hbm/User.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
    <property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="basePersistence" class="com.rksambari.common.basedao.BasePersistenceService">
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
</bean>
```

Following is my Java file to insert into db

```
public class BasePersistenceService{
HibernateTemplate template;


public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
    this.template = template;  
} 

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void save(User user){
    template.save(user);
    template.flush();
}}
```

Remaining all the hbm file and Java pojo files are fine. I hope I'm doing something wrong in my applicationContext.xml file. Please help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code and see if hibernate is displaying any messages in console?

Comment: INFO: HHH00037:Columns: [firstname, password, user_id, address_id, tag, institute_id, username, lastname]
Mar 01, 2018 12:05:09 PM org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger foreignKeys
INFO: HHH00108:Foreign keys: []
Mar 01, 2018 12:05:09 PM org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger indexes
INFO: HHH00126:Indexes: [primary]
Mar 01, 2018 12:05:09 PM org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger schemaUpdateComplete
INFO: HHH00232:Schema update complete


Its a part of message printed in console.